# Facebook, Twitter and Email not working using ShareKit

Tags: facebook, sharekit

I am a new iOS developer and I have created an app where I want to share links to Facebook, Twitter and email. I am using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5. I have visited lot of sites and used lots of sample code, but I am not able to manage this. Using the ShareKit library I am able to share images but not able to share links.

Can any one share me a link or example source code by which I am able to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) demo app. For download please follow [install wiki guide](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit). Original ShareKit is not maintained anymore.